# The LINQ expression could not be translated in CROSS APPLY

Tags: entity-framework, linq, cross-apply

I am trying to get the result of `CROSS APPLY` between a dbSet and a list of object.

```
    public class BudgetRate : BaseEntity
    {
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
        public decimal RateValue { get; set; }
        public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public DateTime ExchangeDate { get; set; }
        public string ExchangeCurrencyCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
List<TestClass> testClasses = new();
// Logic to fill the list
var query = from a in _dbContext.BudgetRate
            from b in testClasses
                 .Where(b => a.ValueDate <= b.ExchangeDate && a.CurrencyCode == b.ExchangeCurrencyCode).ToList()
                 .OrderByDescending(b => a.ValueDate).Take(1)
            select new
            {
                Key = a.ValueDate.ToString() + ',' + a.CurrencyCode,
                a.RateValue,
            };
```

However I am getting the following exception:

```
The LINQ expression 'a => __testClasses_0
    .Where(b => a.ValueDate <= b.ExchangeDate && a.CurrencyCode == b.ExchangeCurrencyCode)
    .AsQueryable()
    .OrderByDescending(b => a.ValueDate)
    .Take(1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'
```

Comment: Fir sure it is not translatable. Remove `.ToList()` from query (after `Where`).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The `ToList()` wasn't there in the first place. I added it to try if it will work, but it didn't in both cases I received the same exception

Comment: `testClasses` is local collection?

Comment: It's a list of `TestClass` defined this way: `List<TestClass> testClasses = new();`

Comment: With EF Core you cannot join to local collection (list in your case).

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do so?

Comment: Alternative is third party libraries like [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). It can translate this query to the SQL. Note that there can be collision in async methods.